# Spring Data Mongo Query Field parameters

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm playing with Spring Data Mongo Query and wondering about the field property parameters.
Here is the example that I got from [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html#d0e4055):

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>
  @Query(value="{ 'firstname' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'firstname' : 1, 'lastname' : 1}")
  List<Person> findByThePersonsFirstname(String firstname);
}
```

The question is: What is the meaning of `1` in `{ 'firstname' : 1, 'lastname' : 1}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 means that both 'firstname' and 'lastname' will be included in the resulted document. For example, if you have 'salary' field you can exclude it from result by typing `'salary': 0`.

Comment: So, basically 1 = TRUE, 0 = FALSE?

Comment: 1 - include field in the result, 0 - exclude. Or, if you do not provide 'fields' falue, all document fields will be included.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MongoTemplate` for querying.First you declare `query` and after that you can declare `criteria`.Below is an example :

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("kademeler.isemriId").is(isemriNo)
                .and("ogag").is(1);
        Query query = new Query(criteria);
        query.fields().exclude("salary"); //for excluding a field, this is "salary" for you
        List<AboneAriza> result = mongoTemplate.find(query, AboneAriza.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, the id of the document is also returned by default, so this in detail will mean, firstname, lastname along with _id of the document will be return, and as some one already answered setting a field to zero will not return that particular field when the document is being returned.